# NagiosXI install fail: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try

Tags: redhat, nagios, rhel7, nagiosxi

I'm trying to install NagiosXI.5.5.8 on a fresh VM image of RHEL7.6 minimal install. It fails on the step 1 of running `./fullinstall` with an error of `[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `nagios-7.repo` repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d` is incorrect. It is looking for an http url but nagios is using https.

`nagios-7.repo`:

```
[nagios-base]
name=Nagios
baseurl=http://repo.nagios.com/nagios/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-NAGIOS-V2

[nagiosxi-deps]
name=Nagios XI Dependencies
baseurl=http://repo.nagios.com/nagiosxi-deps/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-NAGIOS-V2
```

This seems to work:

```
[nagios-base]
name=Nagios
baseurl=https://repo.nagios.com/nagios/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-NAGIOS-V2

[nagiosxi-deps]
name=Nagios XI Dependencies
baseurl=https://repo.nagios.com/nagiosxi-deps/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-NAGIOS-V2
```